# How to do a point in time recovery in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, recovery

I want to do a point in time recovery in postgresql. This is my recovery.conf

```
standby_mode = 'off'
primary_conninfo = 'host=localhost user=postgres port=5432 krbsrvname=postgres'
restore_command = 'cp /home/duc/backup/database/postgre_backupdb/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2017-06-16 9:00:00'
```

But when I start the server I always get this error in log

```
2017-06-17 08:01:53.679 ICT [6984] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-16 16:27:53 ICT
2017-06-17 08:01:53.679 ICT [6984] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2017-06-16 09:00:00+07
cp: cannot stat '/home/duc/backup/database/postgre_backupdb/00000002.history': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/home/duc/backup/database/postgre_backupdb/000000020000000C00000042': No such file or directory
2017-06-17 08:01:53.682 ICT [6984] LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2017-06-17 08:01:53.682 ICT [6984] FATAL:  could not locate required checkpoint record
2017-06-17 08:01:53.682 ICT [6984] HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label".
2017-06-17 08:01:53.683 ICT [6983] LOG:  startup process (PID 6984) exited with exit code 1
2017-06-17 08:01:53.683 ICT [6983] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2017-06-17 08:01:53.684 ICT [6983] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I have try to change the recovery_target_time to other time but still get that error.

How do I do a point in time recovery ?

Comment: Which version of your database ? Please take a look on "25.3.5. Timelines" at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/continuous-archiving.html.

Comment: postgres version is 9.6, the timelines is about recovery_target_timeline my question is about recovery_target_time, so it not help at all :)

Comment: Have You tried the HINT ? 
HINT:  If you are not restoring from a backup, try removing the file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/backup_label".
Perhaps the backup_label still exists due to pg_start_backup() not ended with pg_stop_backup()

Comment: How did you get the backup data directory?  It doesn't seem to match the Wal archive.  No amount of changing the target time can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in recovery.conf file apply only for the duration of the recovery
it, this file provide the parameters that PostgreSQL needs to

## perform an archive recovery of a database, or to act as a log-streaming.

## replication standby.

1. you need to turn on archive_log
2. the log show you there is no "cp: cannot stat '/home/duc/backup/database/postgre_backupdb/000000020000000C00000042': No such file or directory" have no that file it mean database couldn't make checkpoint to archive it.
3. use some tool to do backup such as PG_RMNA (ex: pg_rman restore --recovery-target-time '2017-06-16 9:00:00' -B /BACKUP/pgrman -D $PGDATA -U postgres)